# LTSpice sweep resistance

Tags: ltspice, energy, piezo

I would like to plot the power obtained by this simple recovery circuit (UR1eff^2/R1) according to the value of the resistance R1. But as it is a sinusoidal function, it takes the average value of the voltage i.e. 0. How to plot the power according to the resistance in this case?

Thank you very much for your help.

[image: circuit]

Well the measurement doesn’t work. Here is the result:

[image: error messages from LTspice]

Comment: Do you want to plot the RMS power of R1 for different resistor values, or the effective power (drawn from the power supply every cycle)?

Comment: RMS power is an anomaly; it is meaningless @vtolentino

Comment: You have to correctly label the nets you are measuring. In your case you can label the two sides of the resistor with e.g. X and Y, and modify the commands to `.meas VRMS RMS V(X,Y)` and `.meas VAVG AVG V(X,Y)`

Comment: It worked, thank you so much

Comment: @Julien - Welcome to the site :-) Just one point: Please stop adding your signature to your questions. It breaks [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) site rule. (Even adding the polite "thank you" in the question is borderline discouraged, as being noise by some people.) Stack Exchange sites are different from typical internet forums. You will find more details and rules in the [tour] and [help]. Also see [this page in the help center](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) about what to do when someone answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example how you can calculate the power dynamically:

```
.step param Rload 1 10 1
.meas VRMS RMS V(X)
.meas VAVG AVG  V(X)
.meas PRMS param VRMS**2/Rload
.meas PAVG param VAVG**2/Rload
```

1. Run the simulation

[image: circuit]

2. Open the Spice error log (`ctrl + L`)
3. Right click and select `plot steped meas data`
4. Plot the power that was measured against the resistance as shown below:

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

Does LTSpice have a waveform calculator? If so, you can measure RMS or peak. If not, you can make your own peak detect circuit with an ideal diode and a capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to plot the power obtained by this simple recovery circuit (UR1eff^2/R1) according to the value of the resistance R1. But as it is a sinusoidal function, it takes the average value of the voltage i.e. 0

How is it 0, you have rectified the sine. There is no negative part of sine so average value can't be 0.

Answer (score 0):

> *I would like to plot the power obtained by this simple recovery
> circuit (UR1eff^2/R1) according to the value of the resistance R1. But
> as it is a sinusoidal function, it takes the average value of the
> voltage i.e. 0.*

"*UR1eff^2*" means that the negative values also become positive.